# Magento Call to a member function setAttribute() on a non-object after adding 2 custom fields in address

Tags: php, magento

Using Magento 1.9.0.1, I added a module to insert 2 custom fields to address. Please view the codes in my other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29073842/188331).

After I installed the module, the billing address appears this error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function setAttribute() on a non-object in /home/onceecom/public_html/dev/includes/src/Mage_Eav_Model_Attribute_Data.php on line 80

The page has not been modified to display the new fields, but the error has already appeared. How can I debug such error?

p.s. not sure if it's related, I modified the Customer Address display options in System > Configuration > Customer > Customer Configuration > Address Template > HTML :

```
{{depend prefix}}{{var prefix}} {{/depend}}{{var firstname}} {{depend middlename}}{{var middlename}} {{/depend}}{{var lastname}}{{depend suffix}} {{var suffix}}{{/depend}}<br/>
{{depend company}}{{var company}}<br />{{/depend}}
{{if street1}}{{var street1}}<br />{{/if}}
{{depend street2}}{{var street2}}<br />{{/depend}}
{{depend street3}}{{var street3}}<br />{{/depend}}
{{depend street4}}{{var street4}}<br />{{/depend}}
{{depend chk_commercial}}{{var chk_commercial}}<br />{{/depend}}
{{depend chk_residential}}{{var chk_residential}}<br />{{/depend}}
{{if city}}{{var city}},  {{/if}}{{if region}}{{var region}}, {{/if}}{{if postcode}}{{var postcode}}{{/if}}<br/>
{{var country}}<br/>
{{depend telephone}}T: {{var telephone}}{{/depend}}
{{depend fax}}<br/>F: {{var fax}}{{/depend}}
{{depend vat_id}}<br/>VAT: {{var vat_id}}{{/depend}}
```

The `chk_commercial` and `chk_residential` are the 2 fields I added. Removing these 2 fields in the settings does **not** remove the error.

Comment: What was the purpose of the module that added the custom fields to sales_flat_quote_address. I assume you wanted additional fields for customer address?

Comment: Yes, exactly. 2 columns are added to DB tables `sales_flat_order_address` and `sales_flat_quote_address`

Comment: Your fatal error stems from the attributes created. Additional database columns would not trigger a fatal error. Can you reset your attributes to vanilla setting and then just alter the table to include the additional columns. Though... you only need to alter the sales_flat_order_address table as the quote header table and its children are simply a shopping cart pre-order. Then I would recommend you add an observer to populate the field one way or the other on order creation then access them directly.

Comment: what is "vanilla setting"? and how to add an observer ? what did I miss in  my module code? or the default settings is incorrect ?

Comment: Normally you would use magento admin panel to add additional eav values to a user's address and set them as required/so on. Maybe this is the best approach for you to take as eav tables were made extensible so that users could simply create them from the admin panel. By vanilla I mean either reinstall Magento or restore the tables to their original settings.

Comment: How can I add EAV to user address in Admin Panel ? I searched for tutorials online, most of them instruct me to use module like what I did now.

Comment: Apparently address attributes are build in only for enterprise... admin/customer_address_attribute/ I would explore how enterprise does it and attempt to replicate it would be my best suggestion.

Comment: I can restore the DB & remove the module, but still, I'm unable to figure out what did I miss in my module.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I found out the issue. As of Magento CE 1.9.0.1, the config.xml structure I used becomes invalid.

Thus, I use the following tool to re-generate the module:

http://www.silksoftware.com/magento-module-creator/

Hope this helps others in need.